# Designing class with fields as string arrays

Tags: c#, class

I'm not sure if this is the right title, but here goes.

I have a simple class with many fields and a method that checks these fields. The class looks like below. I removed the accessors for space.

So I call SetAlarms to set the fields to later use them with method AlarmsOk() and other methods. Everything worked fine since the datatable only had one row.

Now the datatable has two rows. So I was thinking of using a struct array to store these two rows. If I continued using the class fields, I'd set them as arrays I would need to initialize each string, which means that I would need to add 100 rows, one per field. One the other hand, I can have a struct array and initialize it two length of 2 with one line.

Is this correct?

```
public class Alarms
{
    private string[] alarm0;
    private string[] alarm1;
    // to Alarm99
    private string[] alarm99;

    public void SetAlarms(DataTable AlarmsTable) 
    {
        int currentRow = 0;

        int rowCount = AlarmsTable.Rows.Count; //AlarmsTable has 2 rows
        alarm0 = new string[rowCount];
        alarm1 = new string[rowCount];
        // to Alarm99
        alarm99 = new string[rowCount];

        foreach (DataRow row in AlarmsTable.Rows)

            alarm0[currentRow] = Convert.ToString(AlarmsTable.Rows[currentRow]["Alarm0"]);
            alarm1[currentRow] = Convert.ToString(AlarmsTable.Rows[currentRow]["Alarm1"]);
            // to Alarm99
            alarm99[currentRow] = Convert.ToString(AlarmsTable.Rows[currentRow]["Alarm99"]);
            currentRow++;
        }
    }

    public bool AlarmsOk()
    {
        //Check if alarms are OK, return true/false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I would rather use some `AlarmData` class and a `List` instead:

```
public class AlarmData
{
    public string Alarm0 { get; set; }
    ...
    public string Alarm99 { get; set; }
}

public class Alarms
{
    private List<AlarmData> alarmData = new List<AlarmData>();

    public void SetAlarms(DataTable AlarmsTable) 
    {
        this.alarmData.Clear();
        foreach (DataRow row in AlarmsTable.Rows)
        {       
            var newData = new AlarmData();
            newData.Alarm0 = Convert.ToString(AlarmsTable.Rows[currentRow]["Alarm0"]);
            ...
            newData.Alarm99 = Convert.ToString(AlarmsTable.Rows[currentRow]["Alarm99"]);

            this.alarmData.Add(newData);
        }
    }

    public bool AlarmsOk()
    {
        //Check if alarms are OK, return true/false
    }
}
```

So you have a class that correspond to your table (and an instance in your list for each row), which is easier to read IMO.

Answer (score 0):

You can use array of arrays:

```
private string[][] alarm;
```

And use it:

```
alarm[0][currentRow] = value;
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like bad design to me. Your OP suggests you are crowbarring everything into a single table.

Rather than have a single `Alarms` class,I think you should have a singular `Alarm` class. This would store information about a single alarm entity only. Then whatever the object is that actually has the alarms (say a `Foo`) would have a collection of `Alarm` objects - so something like

```
public class Foo
{
    public List<Alarm> Alarms { get; set; }
}
```

On the database side you would have a `Foo` table and an `Alarm` table. Your `Alarm` table will have a `FooID` column so you can link each one back to the `Foo`.